# Why the center points created from center of pixels in ERA-5 dataset are not appear in correct places when exported and showed in ArcMap?

Tags: raster, arcmap, google-earth-engine, point

I used [This Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ed417e36ab895002327d4239a66f98d0) to create points from the center of pixels for the [ERA-5 Dataset](https://ERA5-Land%20Hourly%20-%20ECMWF%20Climate%20Reanalysis) in an AOI and then exported them to Drive as a Shapefile and add them to ArcMap. After that, I used [This Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c3420bfc5717aca739b00634458d10fc) to clip a part of the raster and export it to drive to test. The problem is that when I use the code and create Center points from [CHIRPS](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/UCSB-CHG_CHIRPS_DAILY?hl=en), [PERSIAN](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_PERSIANN-CDR?hl=en), or [TRMM](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/TRMM_3B42?hl=en) and export the points and add them to ArcMap, everything is OK as in Figures (1) and (2); but, when I use the code to create center points for [ERA-5](https://ERA5-Land%20Hourly%20-%20ECMWF%20Climate%20Reanalysis), Everything seems to be ok but when I add the Points to ArcMap they are not in the center of Pixels. It is Obvious in Figures (3) and (4). I think the problem is with the raster, but I do not know why and how can I solve it?

[image: Figure 1 - Center Points Created For Persian Dataset in GEE]

[image: Figure 2 - Center Points Created For Persian Dataset, Showing in ArcMAp]

[image: Figure 3 - Center Points Created For ERA-5 Dataset in GEE]

[image: Figure 4 - Center Points Created For ERA-5 Dataset, Showing in ArcMAp]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the points are in a *particular* different place: the exact corners of the pixels.

I'm not familiar with the relevant standards, but I think I've heard about georeferencing of images being able to choose between using coordinates referring to pixel centers or referring to pixel corners. That 1/2-pixel difference would account for this different result, if either your ERA-5 image in ArcMap or the image in Earth Engine's catalog had that option set the wrong way around.

You can test this hypothesis: create a point using simple latitude-longitude coordinates that you type in yourself, then display it on the map in both Earth Engine and ArcGIS. (Earth Engine will default to interpreting latitude and longitude using EPSG:4326, WGS 84; I don't know about ArcGIS but make sure it's set to be the same.) See if the additional point appears in the same place (indicating something is wrong with the point set export/import) or different ones (indicating something is wrong with the image's position in one or the other tool).